# Logstash continue moving data after failover

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I have a large table in MySQL that I want to migrate its data to Elasticsearch using logstash. the table has about 37 million records and 14 gig data.
but after migrating 10 million records from MySQL the pipeline failed do to lack of CPU resource. now i want it to start after the migrated data and continue not start all over again.
i created a logstash pipeline for migrating data here's my input:

```
input {
jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "cot1.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.101:3306/db_name"
    jdbc_user => "databaseuser"
    jdbc_password => "databasepassword"
    jdbc_page_size => 50000
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_validation_timeout => 120
    jdbc_pool_timeout => 180
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "id"
    connection_retry_attempts => 5
    connection_retry_attempts_wait_time => 60
    statement => "SELECT
l.id,
l.created_at,
l.test1_id,
t1.test2_id,
t2.test3_id,
l.user_id,
l.ip,
t3.type,
t3.owner_id,
l.user_agent,
l.agent,
l.country,
l.city,(
    t3.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND t1.deleted_at IS NULL
    AND t2.deleted_at IS NULL
) deleted_at ,
(t2.is_active = 'yes' AND t1.is_active = 'yes') is_active
FROM
    logs l
    INNER JOIN test1 t1 ON t1.id = l.test1_id
    INNER JOIN test2 t2 ON t1.test2_id = t2.id
    INNER JOIN test3 t3 ON t3.id = t2.test3_id"
    }
}
```

the select query is really heavy.

and my filter is just a little ruby script to transform data

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => '
        event.set("eventName","log")
        event.set("user_id",event.get("user_id"))
        event.set("eventDate",event.get("created_at"))
        event.set("[data][created_at]",event.get("created_at"))
        event.set("[data][id]",event.get("id"))
        event.set("[data][test1_id]",event.get("test1_id"))
        event.set("[data][test2_id]",event.get("test2_id"))
        event.set("[data][agent]",event.get("agent"))
        event.set("[data][type]",event.get("type"))
        event.set("[data][ip]",event.get("ip"))
        event.set("[data][test3_id]",event.get("test3_id"))
        event.set("[data][deleted_at]",event.get("deleted_at"))
        event.set("[data][owner_id]",event.get("owner_id"))
        event.set("[data][user_agent]",event.get("user_agent"))
        event.set("[data][is_active]",event.get("is_active"))
        event.set("[data][country]",event.get("country"))
        event.set("[data][city]",event.get("city"))
        event.remove("created_at")
        event.remove("test1_id")
        event.remove("agent")
        event.remove("id")
        event.remove("test2_id")
        event.remove("test3_id")
        event.remove("deleted_at")
        event.remove("type")
        event.remove("is_active")
        event.remove("owner_id")
        event.remove("ip")
        event.remove("user_agent")
        event.remove("country")
        event.remove("city")
        '
    }
}
```

and my output is like this

```
output {
     elasticsearch {
        hosts => "192.168.0.101:9200"
        index => "events"
        document_id => "logs_%{[data][id]}"
    }
}
```

plus I don't want to remove the migrated data yet because on production my codebase is still using MySQL for query and I want to migrate all data and then update my codebase

Comment: I'm not sure, but if your Logstash service has crashed, then it lost the value of the `tracking_column` and will start from the beginning. What you could try is to to edit your sql clause and use a where condition based on the id and the last id you have in elasticsearch.